# cp in script changes Access and Change but not Modify if file is the same?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

When I directly do cp in shell and overwrite an already existing file, the Modify attribute in stat will go with the new timestamp. However, when I run the same command from a script it will change only Access and Change attributes, but not Modify. The file is exactly the same. Why the different behavior? In stat, Modify doesn't change if the file is the same?

Command that I'm running:

```
for file in $BACKUP_PATH"msghtml/messages.es.po_$deploTime"; do 
  filnam="$(sudo basename $file)"; 
  sudo cp -v $file "$FEW_PATH/app/translations/"${filnam%%_*}; 
done
```

Comment: Are you running your script with `sudo` as well? I would suggest removing `sudo` from the script all together.

Comment: This is from the script only; I have to use sudo because I'm running it with another user, but to have access to the server where the command is run I have to go as root.

Comment: It's the same `cp` command -- not part of the shell at all -- no matter if it's invoked from a script or not. Literally an external binary, ie. `/usr/bin/cp`; it has no way of knowing if the shell that invoked it was interactive.

Comment: that said, you're **definitely** overusing `sudo`. There's no way `sudo` can be needed for `basename`, for example.

Comment: ...anyhow, frankly, it's hard to believe the core claim made in this question. Modifying your script itself to run `stat` and showing actual output would be a place to start re: proving the claim made. (Running `bash -x yourscript` to log commands run by the script to make sure they are what you expect is also a agood idea).

Comment: ...btw, consider also running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds; there are several places where the quoting is off, which would cause bugs (potentially ones related to the problem, as they could cause different files to be copied than the ones you think you're operating on) if you had filenames with spaces. That would show up in the `bash -x` logs, which is another reason to show them in the question.

Comment: Run `which cp` n your shell to check if cp is aliased  to `cp` with flags. Incase it is just use the same flags